# File transfered over HTTP only partially written

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying to transfer a binary file over HTTP using NodeJS and Express. The file is not very large but large enough to get me into some troubles (~1.8 Mo).

I am reading the file using fs.readFile(..), then sending it using the built in res.sendFile(..) function. If I execute a curl command and redirect it's result into a new file, the content of the original file is perfectly replicated on the server and I am able to use it.

However, if I do this using NodeJs, by using the http module and a buffer, only 65.5 Ko of the file gets written. 
I tried using the curl-request module, and writing the body to a file. It works slightly better, but still, it copies only 1.7 Mo to the new file, which remains incomplete.

Here is the code I am using to send the file :

```js
app.get('/global_model', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/global-model/weights.bin');
});
```

and the code to receive it (using the http module) :

```js
  const options = {
          hostname: host,
          port: port,
          path: '/global_model',
          method: 'GET',
     };
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
              res.on('data', (d) => {
                 let buffer = new Buffer(d, 'binary');
                 fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/loc-model/weights.bin', buffer, (err) => {
                     if(!err) {
                         resolve();
                     }
                 });
             });
          });
          req.on('error', (error) => {
              reject(error);
          });
          req.end();
      });
```

And using the curl-request module :

```js
let curl = new (require('curl-request'))();
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        curl.get('http://localhost:33333/global_model')
        .then(({statusCode, body, headers}) => {
            fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/loc-model/weights.bin', body, {encoding:'binary'} , (err) => {
                if(!err) {
                    resolve();
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Wireshark shows that there is no loss while handling the request. I am a bit lost on this relatively simple task. 
Am I doing something wrong ?

Edit : I tried using a ReadStream on the buffer, but still not saving the file entierely.

Comment: You are rewriting the file on each new chunk of data you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Your code rewrites the file on each new chunk of data, and resolves immediately after receiving one.

You need to pipe from the HTTP read stream into the file instead – something like this (untested, YMMV).

```
const options = {
  hostname: host,
  port: port,
  path: "/global_model",
  method: "GET",
};
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const req = http.request(options, res => {
    const outStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/loc-model/weights.bin");
    outStream.on("error", reject);
    res.pipe(outStream);
    res.on("end", () => {
      outStream.close();
      resolve();
    });
  });
  req.on("error", reject);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and I am still getting a partially written file (1.7 Mo instead of the full 1.8 Mo)